# Monterey Terminal App does not respond to keyboard shortcuts

Tags: terminal, monterey

The problem below only started when I upgraded to Monterey.

When I use the System Preferences > Shortcuts > (App Shortcuts) to set a shortcut key for an item on the Terminal > Shell > New Window submenu, the keyboard shortcut does not work.  The problem isn't with the key sequence itself, I can assign it to open a new private window in my browser, for instance, and it works.

The shortcut is listed in the Shell > New Window submenu, but when I press the sequence it appears to make the Edit menu blink if the Terminal window is selected, and does nothing otherwise.

Comment: What precisely do you have in the Shortcuts page? e.g `Grass` or `Shell->New Window->Grass`? [A picture might help]. Does it work if you manually select from the menu?

Comment: @Tetsujin I have only the text of the configuration, e.g., Grass.

This worked in Mac OS 11, and works with say Firefox, "New Private Window" (minus the quotation marks)